# Subspace criterion (zero vector?)

Tags: linear-algebra

This may be a poor question but it is one that I cannot wrap my head around.

The theorem I am presented with is as follows:

> (Subspace criterion) Suppose $V$ is vector space over $F$.
>   A nonempty subset $U ⊆ V$ is a subspace if and only if $U$ is closed for addition
>   and multiplication with scalars.

When proceeding to worked examples, I noticed that the first property that is checked when proving a set is a subspace using the above criterion is whether the zero vector exists. However, this property is not mentioned in the criterion?

I assume that there is some connection between a set being closed under addition and it has a zero vector but I am failing to deduce it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Closed by addition and closed by additive inverses, so $u + (-u) = 0$ must be in the set.  Equivalently, closed by scalar multiplication, $0\cdot u = 0$ must be in the set.

Comment: In short, $0$ is a scalar.

Comment: "Equivalently, closed by scalar multiplication, 0⋅u=0 must be in the set. "
That makes sense to me. Though in terms of addition, why must the additive inverse exist? I understand that it is in the definition of a vector space but the criterion solely mentions being closed under addition and scalar multiplication. My apologies if I seem pedantic about this, I am trying to understand it as best I can.

Comment: I think I am relying on the criterion exactly as it is written. It does not mention that the subset must satisfy the remaining vector space axioms which is where I am getting confused. Edit: I think I understand now! U is a subset of V which is a vector space. Hence, U automatically satisfies most of the vector space axioms so all that needs to be shown are those axioms mentioned in the criterion if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Sometimes checking that the zero vector is contained in the subset is the most straightforward way to check that the subset is nonempty. Checking non-emptiness is a requirement for the subset to be a subspace. Hence you will find that the first step in most of the examples is to check that the zero vector is contained in the subset.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a subspace of $V$ of dimension $1$, $U$, where the entire subspace is spanned by scalar multiples of some element $\vec{u}$.

No matter what $\vec{u}$ is, we can always construct a sum of the form:

$$\vec{u} + -\vec{u}$$

This is equal to $\vec{0}$ by definition, so the zero vector needs to be in the subspace in order for the subspace to be closed with respect to vector addition.

Answer (score -1):

Let 0'=additive identity of field F,now since vector subspace S is closed with respect to scalar multiplication,hence 0'(a)€S
0'(a)=(0'+0')a  {a€S}
0'(a)=0'a+0'a
0'(a)=0''€S{where 0''=zero of vector subspace},,Hence there is a connection between closed wrt scalar multiplication and existence of Zero of subspace